# Put data from a csv file into an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I need to be able to take data from a CSV file (which has been chosen by the user via `<input type="file" id="fileInput">`) and put it into an array. Id rather avoid using jquery as I haven't used it before but any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>
    Select a text file: 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  </div>
  <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>
</div>
<p id="csvData"></p>
<button onClick="test()">Show Text</button>

<script>
function test (){
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;
  var csvType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

  if (file.type.match(csvType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("csvData").innerHTML=reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);  
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: And what format is the CSV in, and what do you expect to get back?

Comment: Forgot to include the data in the csv file. It reads like this :

Comment: test,test2  I want to be able to return the string test 2 when [1] is used

Comment: `csvType` is wrong... a csv use `text/csv` as a mimetype

Comment: tried it with text/csv, doesn't work at all. Simply returns not supported.

Answer (score 5):

To process a `csv` type file, there's two things you need to do:

- Split in to lines
- Split in to columns

You can do both by using `String.prototype.split`. This method splits a string into an array. To split on each new line, use the regex `/\n/`. To split each column, use the character that is used in your data (probably `,` or `;`).

Here's an example:

```js
// Create an array of arrays
// Remove first line
// Split by ","
function process(dataString) {
  var lines = dataString
    .split(/\n/)                     // Convert to one string per line
    .map(function(lineStr) {
        return lineStr.split(",");   // Convert each line to array (,)
    })
    .slice(1);                       // Discard header line
  
  return JSON.stringify(lines, null, 2);
}


function test() {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;
  var csvType = 'text/csv';
  if (file.type.match(csvType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("csvData").innerHTML = process(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>
    Select a text file:
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
  </div>
  <pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
  <pre id="csvData"></pre>
  <button onClick="test()">Show Text</button>
</div>
```

Store this data snippet as a `.csv` file to test:

```
ONE,TWO,THREE
1,2,3
2,4,6
3,6,9
```

An additional note: if there is a header row in your data, like in the example above, I'd strongly suggest to not map to arrays, but to objects. This makes your code easier to read and use:

```js
// Create an array of objects
// Use the first line as keys
// Split by ","
function process(dataString) {
  var lines = dataString
    .split(/\n/)
    .map(function(lineStr) {
        return lineStr.split(",");
    });
  
  var keys = lines[0];

  var objects = lines
    .slice(1)
    .map(function(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
        obj[keys[i]] = val; 
        return obj;
      }, {});
    });
  
  return JSON.stringify(objects, null, 2);
}


function test() {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;
  var csvType = 'text/csv';
  if (file.type.match(csvType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("csvData").innerHTML = process(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>
    Select a text file:
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
  </div>
  <pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
  <pre id="csvData"></pre>
  <button onClick="test()">Show Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, just returns "not supported" when I choose the csv file. Worked on the code I showed in my question.

Comment: I changed the `csvType` to `text/csv` in my snippet for testing. Change it back to whatever type you're using before trying it out. I don't know what you'll get when you try to parse an excel file though. Have you exported to `.csv` or are you trying to load a `.xls`?

Comment: Tried it and it works but I don't think you understand what I wanted it to do. I just wanted it to take the data from the csv file and place it in to an array. I didn't want it to print the data from the array to the screen only to place it into an array within a variable which I can use for other functions later, not print anything to the screen.

Comment: You're expecting me to deliver a snippet you can copy and paste, but what I tried to do was to show you *how* you can solve your problem. Printing it to screen is just the means to show you what is happening, not the goal. If you would take the time to read the answer properly, you'll see a `process` method that makes an array of each line. In the future, when somebody takes the time to help you out, try to invest some time as well in to trying to understand the suggestion, and don't just say "Doesn't work"

Comment: TL;DR: Copy the `process` method, remove the `JSON.stringify` from its return statement, and you're ready to go.

Comment: @user3297291 thank you for you this answer. I've been tinkering with your sample code to try to get out a JSON object that I can iterate through, but my JS is super rusty and I'm probably just missing something obvious. I'd be grateful for a pointer.

Comment: If you link me a question on stackoverflow or a snippet in a fiddle/codepen, I'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got to the point where I'm getting at the object, so I think I'm over the hump. But FWIW, here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/strohmy/pen/yvpOdL