# split csv where fields contain commas

Tags: javascript, csv

Thanks to the answer posted here: [Put data from a csv file into an array (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362456/put-data-from-a-csv-file-into-an-array-javascript) I have been able to split a csv file in the manner I need to but I have come across a problem with the output. Nothing to do with the code as it works just as I wanted it to. The issue relates to the source data.

The csv files are provided to me as is so I did not realise that they had fields that contained commas. This means the split doesn't work as needed.

This is the code I am using:

```
$.get("export.csv", function process(dataString) {
    var lines = dataString
    .split(/\n/)
    .map(function(lineStr) {
        return lineStr.split(",");
    });
  
  var keys = lines[0];

  var objects = lines
    .slice(1)
    .map(function(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
        obj[keys[i]] = val; 
        return obj;
      }, {});
    });
  
  console.log(objects);
})
```

This gives me the output in this format:

```
{
    "PROBLEM_NUMBER": "ticket_number",
    "CALLER_NAME": "\"surname",
    "PRIORITY": " forename\"",
    "CALL_TIME": "4",
    "CALL_DETAILS": "date",
    "RESOLVER": "group",
    "RESTORING_GROUP": "\"surname",
    "RESOLVING_GROUP": " forename\"",
    "RESTORATION_TIME": "group",
    "RAG_STATUS": "group",
    "CALL_STATUS": "date",
    "CALL_TYPE": "RED",
    "RESTORATION_CODE": "Closed",
    "SUBMITTER_GROUP": "Problem",
    "ASSIGNEE_GROUP": "resolution",
    "ASSIGNEE_NAME": "group",
    "RESOLVED_DATE_TIME": "group",
    "RESTORED_DATE_TIME": "",
    "TIME_WITH_TEAM": "date",
    "MONTH/YEAR\r": "date",
    "undefined": "Jan-21\r"
}
```

As you can see, the final field is "undefined" due to 2 fields containing a comma and splitting incorrectly.

I know I need to use regex to modify the split correctly however I don't understand or know where to put it. Is anyone able to assist me please?

Thanks

Comment: if your data includes characters used to control the encoding, those characters should be escaped upfront and there's no way to parse it correctly otherwise unless you make lots of assumption to mitigate the problem.. this is just a reminder before doing any further discussion

Comment: Thanks @DiegoDeVita. When you say "make lots of assumption to mitigate the problem" what are you referring to? I only ask as these csv files will be uploaded to the server by another team prior to being processed by the script. The csv files themselves are direct exports from an application

Comment: Looks like this third-party application export is your problem then. Unless you are able to add \ escape characters to your entries - then you should do that probably.

Comment: @LeightonJames To better highlight the problem I was talking about you should share the line producing that output. Also to better make it clear. Anyway the assumptions I meant it's how your parser should discern a comma intended to split fields from the comma intended to be part of a field content. Usually you are supposed to escape the comma in the second case. Something like `field1,field2,field3\,containingEscapedComma,field4`. So that your parser will read `\,` as a field comma instead of separation comma. Plus you'll need to escape the slash as well like doubling it.

Comment: If you don't have that escaping strategy you can make weak assumptions like counting the commas in the line before parsing and guessing which one is not a separation comma. But as you can see you have no perfect rule to cover the entire space. The problem is your serialization (how those "records" get translated to string) that doesn't take into account ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem so thought I would post here for anyone else that may come across a similar issue:

To resolve it I declared the regex string as a variable and then called that in the .split() instruction.

The regex string I used was - /("[^"]+"|[^,]+)*,/g

My code now looks like this:

```
$.get("export.csv", function process(dataString) {
    var regex = /("[^"]+"|[^,]+)*,/g;
    var lines = dataString
    .split(/\n/)
    .map(function(lineStr) {
       return lineStr.split(regex);
    });
  var keys = lines[0];
  var objects = lines
    .slice(1)
    .map(function(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
        obj[keys[i]] = val;
        return obj;
      }, {});
    });
  console.log(objects);
})
```

This gives me the correct output I need and maps all values accordingly